# Stop Words into a string

Tags: php, stop-words

I want to create a function in PHP that will return true when it finds that in the string there are some bad words.

Here is an example:

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
if(the words in the stopwords variable are found in the string) {
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

Please assume that `$stopwords` variable is an array of values, like:

```
$stopwords = array('fuc', 'dic', 'pus');
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [determine if a string contains one of a set of words in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916261/determine-if-a-string-contains-one-of-a-set-of-words-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

```
// the function assumes the $stopwords to be an array of strings that each represent a
//  word that should not be in $string
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) 
{  
     // input parameters validation excluded for brevity..

     // take each of the words in the $stopwords array
     foreach($stopwords as $badWord)
     {
         // if the $badWord is found in the $string the strpos will return non-FALSE        
         if(strpos($string, $badWord) !== FALSE))
           return TRUE;
     }
     // if the function hasn't returned TRUE yet it must be that no bad words were found
     return FALSE;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

- `\b` matches a word boundary, use it to match only whole words
- use flag `i` to perform case-insensitive matches

Match each word like so:

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
    foreach ($stopwords as $stopword) {
        $pattern = '/\b' . $stopword . '\b/i';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$stopwords = array('fuc', 'dic', 'pus');

$bad = stopWords('confucius', $stopwords); // true
$bad = stopWords('what the Fuc?', $stopwords); // false
```

A shorter version, inspired by an answer to this question: [determine if a string contains one of a set of words in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916261/determine-if-a-string-contains-one-of-a-set-of-words-in-an-array) is to use `implode` to create one big expression:

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
    $pattern = '/\b(' . implode('|', $stopwords) . ')\b/i';
    return preg_match($pattern, $string) > 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I know if it returns true or false? Also does it work with any of the bad words in the array, or they must be all there in the string?

Comment: I only need to return it true or false if it find ANY of those bad words in the phrase..I think this function does not do it..it is for checking word by word..am I wrong?

Comment: It returns true if `$string` contains any of the words in `$stopwords`, otherwise false. Just as you asked. I updated the examples a bit, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: works only with the first word of the array, but not with all the other bad words

Answer (score 0):

```
function stopWords($string, $stopwords) {
    $words=explode(' ', $string); //splits the string into words and stores it in an array
    foreach($stopwords as $stopword)//loops through the stop words array
    {
        if(in_array($stopword, $words)) {//if the current stop word exists 
            //in the words contained in $string then exit the function 
            //immediately and return true
            return true;
        }
    }
    //else if none of the stop words were in $string then return false
    return false;
}
```

---

I'm assuming here that `$stopwords` is an array to begin with. It should be if it's not.