# Check for multiple words in a string and show found/not found words

Tags: php, regex

I am checking for multiple words in a string using using the example by `anubhava` [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518368/php-check-if-string-contains-multiple-words/10518544) However, I am not sure how to show the words that are found and ones that are not found in the string. Any ideas how to achieve that. The code I am using looks like below.

```
$bad_words = array("yo","hi");
$sentence = "yo you your";

preg_match_all('/\w+/', $sentence, $m);
echo ( array_diff ( $m[0], $bad_words ) === $m[0] ) ? "no bad words found\n" :
                                                      "bad words found\n";
```

Comment: I think I'd probably use `preg_split()` to divide the string into an array of words, then go from there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define what a **word** is in this context. For example, is "*pancake*" one word or two? If you search for "*pan*" should it return true if "*pancake*" is found? Also, is "*A.I.*" a word? Is "*2020*" a word? What about "*fast-track*"? Should the search be case-sensitive? Should it include partial finds? If you just want a simple, needle/haystack search like `strpos` then the solution is trivial.

```
$searchWords = ["yo","hi"];
$sentence    = "yo you your";
$wordsFound  = [];

foreach ($searchWords as $word) {
    if (stripos($sentence, $word) !== false) {
        $wordsFound[$word] = true;
    }
}

echo "Words found: ", implode(",", array_keys($wordsFound)); // Words found: yo
```

To find the words that weren't found in `$searchWords` you'd just do `$wordsNotFound = array_diff($searchWords, array_keys($wordsFound))`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks so much!